# How to extend a connected graphic lines in KiCad 6?

Tags: kicad, line, graphics

How can I extend or decrease the length of a connected graphic line in the Schematic Editor of KiCad 6?

Below is in blue ovals the pictogram and two examples marked.

I can remember I could change the length of the lines with the 'g' hotkey, but in KiCad 6 this does not seem to work anymore (it moves it instead).

Is there any how to prevent removing/redrawing the lines every time I want to change them?

[image]

Comment: KiCAD 6 has moved from a "hover and press ___ key" mantra to "click on item and press ___ key".

Comment: It still seems the g hotkey does work but it moves it, not change the l ength.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Click the line and move the black dot on the end as needed

[image: KiCad graphic line]

Comment: I've had plenty of trouble switching to KiCad 6 too. Overcoming version 5 muscle memory is hard.

Comment: I am not a die hard KiCad user (electronics is 'just' a hobby), so for me the switching is easier.